# unable to view PDF after uploading to s3. uploading images works fine (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've been using aws-sdk to upload images for quite some time now with no issue but have just recently needed to upload a pdf. I thought I could use the same functionality

It looks like I get a successful response when uploading but when I try to open the PDF I get `Failed to load PDF document.`

I've tried using putObject instead of uploadObject with no luck.

Here is the code I'm using currently

```
var deferred = q.defer();
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var buf = new Buffer( file.replace( /^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '' ), 'base64' );
var params = { 
    Bucket: config.bucket, 
    Key: config.environment + '/' + fileName, 
    ContentType: fileType, 
    Body: buf 
};


s3.upload( params, function( err, data ) {
    err ? console.log( err ) : console.log( data );
    deferred.resolve( data );
} );
return deferred.promise;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha!

So i was stripping the mime type from my data on line 3 so that ONLY the file data remained BUT pdf files don't have a mime type that start with image so it wasn't getting picked up by my regex. Its actually `application/pdf`

I found a better way of doing this removes mime type regardless of file type. Replace line three with:

```
var fileWithoutMimeType = file.match( /,(.*)$/ )[ 1 ];
var buf = new Buffer( fileWithoutMimeType, 'base64' );
```

Comment: This fails if there is no mime type in your base64 string

Comment: Using without mime-type, PDF is uploading but when accessing Location (the final URL), file is not opening in browser instead it is downloading as without pdf ext. I have to use adobe to open. Any solution so that it should open in browser? Thanks!